Why won't tsc --noEmit run in my GitHub Actions jest.yml?
This command won't work in any form:
yarn tsc --noEmit
npx tsc --noEmit
tsc noEmit

All of them work in a terminal window.
Here's the complete jest.yml:
name: Run Jest Tests

on:
  push:
    branches: [main]
  pull_request:
    branches: [main]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: macos-latest

    steps:

    - name: tsc version
      run: |
        yarn add typescript@5.7.2
        yarn tsc --version
        yarn tsc --noEmit

    - name: Checkout code
      uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Set up Node.js
      uses: actions/setup-node@v2
      with:
        node-version: '20.10.0'
 
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: yarn install

    - name: Set Yarn Version
      run: yarn set version 4.5.3

    - name: Install Watchman
      run: brew install watchman

    - name: Install CocoaPods
      run: sudo gem install cocoapods

    - name: Install iOS dependencies
      run: |
        cd ios
        pod install
        cd ..

    - name: Set Yarn Version
      run: yarn set version 4.5.3

    - name: Yarn install latest
      run: yarn install 

    - name: Run Jest tests
      run: yarn test

Every other line executes perfectly, including the install of TypeScript, and the execution of:
tsc --version

and:
npm install -g tsc

worked too.
Here's what the output for the tsc section looks like:
Run npm install -g typescript@5.7.2

added 1 package in 1s
Version 5.7.2
Version 5.7.2
tsc: The TypeScript Compiler - Version 5.7.2

COMMON COMMANDS

  tsc
  Compiles the current project (tsconfig.json in the working directory.)

  tsc app.ts util.ts
  Ignoring tsconfig.json, compiles the specified files with default compiler options.

  tsc -b
  Build a composite project in the working directory.

  tsc --init
  Creates a tsconfig.json with the recommended settings in the working directory.

  tsc -p ./path/to/tsconfig.json
  Compiles the TypeScript project located at the specified path.

  tsc --help --all
  An expanded version of this information, showing all possible compiler options

  tsc --noEmit
  tsc --target esnext
  Compiles the current project, with additional settings.

COMMAND LINE FLAGS

--help, -h
Print this message.

--watch, -w
Watch input files.

--all
Show all compiler options.

--version, -v
Print the compiler's version.

--init
Initializes a TypeScript project and creates a tsconfig.json file.

--project, -p
Compile the project given the path to its configuration file, or to a folder with a 'tsconfig.json'.

--showConfig
Print the final configuration instead of building.

--build, -b
Build one or more projects and their dependencies, if out of date

COMMON COMPILER OPTIONS

--pretty
Enable color and formatting in TypeScript's output to make compiler errors easier to read.
type: boolean
default: true

--declaration, -d
Generate .d.ts files from TypeScript and JavaScript files in your project.
type: boolean
default: `false`, unless `composite` is set

--declarationMap
Create sourcemaps for d.ts files.
type: boolean
default: false

--emitDeclarationOnly
Only output d.ts files and not JavaScript files.
type: boolean
default: false

--sourceMap
Create source map files for emitted JavaScript files.
type: boolean
default: false

--noEmit
Disable emitting files from a compilation.
type: boolean
default: false

--target, -t
Set the JavaScript language version for emitted JavaScript and include compatible library declarations.
one of: es5, es6/es2015, es2016, es2017, es2018, es2019, es2020, es2021, es2022, es2023, es2024, esnext
default: es5

--module, -m
Specify what module code is generated.
one of: none, commonjs, amd, umd, system, es6/es2015, es2020, es2022, esnext, node16, nodenext, preserve
default: undefined

--lib
Specify a set of bundled library declaration files that describe the target runtime environment.
one or more: es5, es6/es2015, es7/es2016, es2017, es2018, es2019, es2020, es2021, es2022, es2023, es2024, esnext, dom, dom.iterable, dom.asynciterable, webworker, webworker.importscripts, webworker.iterable, webworker.asynciterable, scripthost, es2015.core, es2015.collection, es2015.generator, es2015.iterable, es2015.promise, es2015.proxy, es2015.reflect, es2015.symbol, es2015.symbol.wellknown, es2016.array.include, es2016.intl, es2017.arraybuffer, es2017.date, es2017.object, es2017.sharedmemory, es2017.string, es2017.intl, es2017.typedarrays, es2018.asyncgenerator, es2018.asynciterable/esnext.asynciterable, es2018.intl, es2018.promise, es2018.regexp, es2019.array, es2019.object, es2019.string, es2019.symbol/esnext.symbol, es2019.intl, es2020.bigint/esnext.bigint, es2020.date, es2020.promise, es2020.sharedmemory, es2020.string, es2020.symbol.wellknown, es2020.intl, es2020.number, es2021.promise, es2021.string, es2021.weakref/esnext.weakref, es2021.intl, es2022.array, es2022.error, es2022.intl, es2022.object, es2022.string, es2022.regexp, es2023.array, es2023.collection, es2023.intl, es2024.arraybuffer, es2024.collection, es2024.object/esnext.object, es2024.promise/esnext.promise, es2024.regexp/esnext.regexp, es2024.sharedmemory, es2024.string/esnext.string, esnext.array, esnext.collection, esnext.intl, esnext.disposable, esnext.decorators, esnext.iterator, decorators, decorators.legacy
default: undefined

--allowJs
Allow JavaScript files to be a part of your program. Use the 'checkJS' option to get errors from these files.
type: boolean
default: false

--checkJs
Enable error reporting in type-checked JavaScript files.
type: boolean
default: false

--jsx
Specify what JSX code is generated.
one of: preserve, react, react-native, react-jsx, react-jsxdev
default: undefined

--outFile
Specify a file that bundles all outputs into one JavaScript file. If 'declaration' is true, also designates a file that bundles all .d.ts output.

--outDir
Specify an output folder for all emitted files.

--removeComments
Disable emitting comments.
type: boolean
default: false

--strict
Enable all strict type-checking options.
type: boolean
default: false

--types
Specify type package names to be included without being referenced in a source file.

--esModuleInterop
Emit additional JavaScript to ease support for importing CommonJS modules. This enables 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports' for type compatibility.
type: boolean
default: false

You can learn about all of the compiler options at https://aka.ms/tsc

Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
0s


So what doesn't work? What happens? Why are you installing things before you've even checked out the Yarn lockfile (and why with such outdated actions)?

1 tsc command runs but doeesn't recognize the --noemit flag, so it gives a list of possible commands, the way it does when you enter a flag it doesn't recognize. 2 who says I didn't check out the yarn.lock file?  3. what do mean 'outdated actions.' Are there newer, groovier ones?
I'm new to github actions, so happy to learn! Updated to show output from the failed tsc command.


--noEmit is a perfectly valid flag, as you can see from the list. It doesn't know what you expect it to do, though, because: compile what files, with what config? 2. ...you do. That's what your workflow does; you haven't checked out anything at that point. 3. I mean literally what I say: the versions of actions you're using (e.g. checkout) are outdated (2 < 4). I expect the GHA UI contains warnings you're ignoring. https://docs.github.com/en/actions/writing-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepsuses


thanks for the link! I'm taking a udemy course and reading a packt book on gha right now. I promise I'll get better at it. this was very helpful.

I suspect the reason the actions are outdated is because i got them from copilot and chatgpt, which seem to always be versions behind of whatever software I'm working with.
